# How to set Active plugins as the default screen?

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, wp-redirect

In my testing environment, I've got one hundred plugins. I'm more interested in seeing first the **Active** plugins than the complete list (`All`).

How can I change the default screen for the <kbd>Plugins</kbd> menu item?

[image]

Comment: [| `Active Elsewhere`](https://github.com/brasofilo/Network-Deactivated-but-Active-Elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options, modify the menu link `href` attribute or redirect the main screen.

### Modify menu

Alter the global variable `$submenu`. This method works for Single and Multisite.
Problem: the submenu item `Installed Plugins` doesn't show in bold.

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'b5f_plugins_redirect_to_active' );

function b5f_plugins_redirect_to_active() 
{
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['plugins.php'][5][2] .= "?plugin_status=active";
    return;
}
```

### Redirect page

Hook into `load-plugins.php`. Multisite detection is needed, but there are no UI problems.

```
add_action( 'load-plugins.php', 'b5f_ms_plugins_redirect_to_active' );

function b5f_ms_plugins_redirect_to_active() 
{
    // Trick, plugin_status is only false in WP default screen
    // ['action'] prevents us interfering with activation/deactivation 
    if( isset( $_GET['plugin_status'] ) || isset( $_GET['action'] ) )
        return;

    // Check for MS dashboard, redirect accordingly
    if( is_network_admin() )
        wp_redirect( network_admin_url( 'plugins.php?plugin_status=active' ) );
    else
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'plugins.php?plugin_status=active' ) );

    exit();
}
```

---

---

And a couple of extras:

#### 1) Rename the main link to **`Active`**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rename_submenu_item', 99 );

function rename_submenu_item() 
{
    global $submenu;
    foreach( $submenu['plugins.php'] as $key => $value )
    {
        if( in_array( 'activate_plugins', $value ) ) 
            $submenu['plugins.php'][$key][0] = __( 'Active' );
    }
}
```

#### 2) Add a submenu to access **`All`**

The submenu link is hacked, as well as some jQuery printed to fix the submenus `active` state:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_admin_wpse_44270' );
add_action( 'admin_head-plugins.php', 'highlight_menu_item_wpse_44270' );

function menu_admin_wpse_44270() 
{
    add_submenu_page(
        'plugins.php',
        'Drafts', 
        '<span id="my-all-plugins">All</span>', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'plugins.php?plugin_status=all'
    );
}

function highlight_menu_item_wpse_44270()
{
    if( isset( $_GET['plugin_status'] ) && 'all' == $_GET['plugin_status'] )
    {       
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
            {
                var reference = $('#my-all-plugins').parent().parent();
                // add highlighting to our custom submenu
                reference.addClass('current');
                //remove higlighting from the default menu
                reference.parent().find('li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('current');             
            });     
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Same technique for themes with `load-theme-install.php`, `$_GET['tab']` and `theme-install.php?tab=install`.